# Error when loading R and packages loading

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to use R and there is no way to make it run.

Error is the following:

```
> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
Error in nchar(homeDir) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="D:/OneDrive - Facultad de Agronom�a - Universidad de Buenos Aires/Documentos": El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada
Error in nchar(homeDir) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
```

There are many questions like this in many posts but can't find the solution yet.

Comment: R didn't find the path, maybe it's due to special character in the path 'Facultad de Agronom�a', can you try to run R from D:/ directly to test the hypothesis ? you can specify working directory with `setwd('D:/')` and then run `library(raster)`

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, just need to correct the PATH value in Advanced System Configuration, and add a new value: R_USER with same path. See image below:
[image: Solution in image]